# Cannot Start RabbitMQ node after erlang cookie change

Tags: rabbitmq, rhel7, rabbitmqctl

I am new to RabbitMQ.  Trying to make cluster of 3 nodes on RHEL 7 server. Need to make node3 as master and node1,node2 as its slaves.   I copied  .erlang.cookie content of master node to the slave nodes. Tried to make cluster but nodedown error msg comes up.

However,as a part of troubleshooting discussed in here previously, I killed rabbit process.

Stopped rabbitmq broker , Trying to start the broker but couldn't.
Issued "systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service"
and then 
issued "journalctl -xe" for more details on the error

Error Message :

**

```
Jan 29 03:56:37 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]:
 Starting RabbitMQ broker...
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun starting up.
Jan 29 03:56:38 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 5041.
Jan 29 03:56:38 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 5043.
Jan 29 03:56:38 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmq-server[4839]: {"could not start kernel pid",application_controller,"error in config file \"/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config\" (5): s
Jan 29 03:56:39 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmq-server[4839]: Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Jan 29 03:56:39 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmq-server[4839]: could not start kernel pid (application_controller) (error in config file "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config" (5): synt
Jan 29 03:56:39 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 5222.
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 5223.
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 5224.
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: Stopping and halting node rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02 ...
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02: nodedown
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: DIAGNOSTICS
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: ===========
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: attempted to contact: [rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02]
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02:
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: *** connected to epmd (port 4369) on vmrabbitmqt02
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: no other nodes on vmrabbitmqt02
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: * suggestion: start the node
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: current node details:**
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-51@vmrabbitmqt02'
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: - home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmqctl[5115]: - cookie hash: E8X5sOmIM3Y+Ju6lgvSIhA==
Jan 29 03:56:40 vmrabbitmqt02 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
```

**

v

[* epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDcGd.png)

[Snapshot of rabbitmq-env.conf file along with details of hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf7pd.png) 
Please suggest some measures at the earliest.

Comment: please post your `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` most likely you have an error there

Comment: Posted the config file. 

Can you please suggest what am I missing here ?

Comment: ` (error in config file "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config" (5):` I read this error

Comment: I placed the config file from old server and changed the server names in the config file. 
Now I can see nodedown error and it is not getting started.
I issued 
systemctl enable rabbitmq-server.service

system start rabbitmq-server.service

rabbitmqctl start_app

Comment: @Gabriele
Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

Config File used :

```
[root@vmrabbitmqt02 rabbitmq]# cat rabbitmq.config
% This file managed by Puppet
% Template Path: rabbitmq/templates/rabbitmq.config
[
{rabbit,
[{cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@vmrabbitmqt01', 'rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02', 'rabbit@vmrabbitmqt03'], disc}},
{cluster_partition_handling, ignore},
{ssl_listeners, [5671]},
{ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/rabbitmq_wildcard_root_ca.crt"},
                {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/rabbitmq_wildcard.crt"},
                {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/rabbitmq_wildcard.key"},
                {verify,verify_none},
                {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]},
{default_user, <<"guest">>},
{default_pass, <<"guest">>}
]}
].
% EOF
```

I did an exit from root user.
Logged in again ..
Now Getting a node down error..

Stopping node rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02 ...

Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02: nodedown

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: [rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02]

rabbit@vmrabbitmqt02:

- connected to epmd (port 4369) on vmrabbitmqt02
- epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
- TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
- suggestion: hostname mismatch?
- suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
- suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

current node details:

- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-90@vmrabbitmqt02'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: xy56ebUJo+5exKrQIexXrg==

Comment: Please suggest if I am missing something.